# Keeping different dictionary versions in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries in Python.

```
send_this = []

fruits = {'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}
template = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'coconut'}
for i in fruits.keys():
    send_this.append(template[i] = fruits[i])
```

This updates `template` and adds it to `send_this` but every iteration updates all the values stored in `send_this` instead of just adding a unique one.

I want the final result to be different dicts inside the list i.e

```
[{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'coconut'}, {'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}]
```

but what I'm getting is something like this

```
[{'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}, {'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}]
```

I'm trying not to create the dictionary on the fly for each iteration since the vast majority of the dictionary doesn't need to change for the whole loop.

Comment: this is because you are adding the same object (i.e. references to the same dict) to the list each time

Comment: `send_this.append(template[i] = fruits[i])` is assignment inside an expression which would give a `SyntaxError`.  Is that really your code?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What is this: `send_this.append(template[i] = fruits[i])`?  An assignment isn't a value in Python, so it can't be appended to a list, and if it could it would be a string, not a dict

Comment: `for i in fruits.keys()` Tip: the use of `i` as your variable will be momentarily confusing for a reader.  `i` is traditionally used for an integer index.  `k` or `key` are common ways people name a key.

Comment: This code produces a SyntaxError, `send_this.append(template[i] = fruits[i])` because `template[i] = fruits[i]` is not an expression, it is a statement

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, the code isn't functional, should of tested it. I think I got the idea across for my issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" is that you keep adding the template dict to the list, so it's the same object in each position of the list, so your list is holding three references to the same object.

You need to create a new dict one way or another for each loop iteration.  Here's a simple way which will work as long as your dict doesn't itself include containers (in which case you'd need a deep copy):

```
send_this = []

fruits = {'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}
template = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'coconut'}
for i in fruits.keys():
    d = template.copy()
    d[i] = fruits[i]
    send_this.append(d)

print(send_this)
```

Doing this with deepcopy you would:

```
import copy
template = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'coconut'}
d = copy.deepcopy(template)
d[i] = fruits[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `send_this` variable with a reference to your dictionaries:

```
fruits = {'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}
template = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'coconut'}

send_this = [fruits, template]
print(send_this)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 'apricot', 'b': 'bagel', 'c': 'carrot'}, {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'coconut'}]
```